# Why my export function call every time on change TextInput

Tags: typescript, react-native

HI there here is my code in react and type script Why this console.log , calls every time that my text filed change trigger ..

```
export default function TabOneScreen({
  navigation,
}) {
  
  const [out_1, set_out1] = useState('');
  const [out_2, set_out2] = useState('');
  const [main_device, setMain_dev] = useState('');
 
  


  console.log("run every time .. on text changed .."); // on change  text run every time ..
 // here I had some function for init textInput value and don't want to run every time ..
  


  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={{
      }}>


        <TextInput
          value={out_1}
          onChangeText={(username) => set_out1(username)}. 
        />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because every time you change the state, the function will be called with the new state. The main lifecycle of a react component is: `Mounting` , `Updating`, `Unmounting`.
When you first render the element, it's in the mounting phase. After that, when you change the state of the element, or it's properties, then it's going to be updated. And when the element will be removed, it's in the unmounting phase. Each update of the state makes the whole component rendered again using the same function. To only call this once, you need to use it at the mounting phase. To do this:

```
useEffect(() => console.log("run every time .. on text changed ..") , [])
```

`useEffect` takes two arguments, the first is the function to be run, and the second is the triggering state to run this function. Here, `[]` just means to run this only at the mounting phase. To trigger another state and running at it, you put it inside the array. For example, suppose you want it to run at only when out_1 state changes, you can add it at the second parameter:

```
useEffect(() => console.log("run every time .. on out_1 changes ..") , [out_1])
```

This means that only run this function when out_1 changes.
If you are going to fetch data from an API or any other resource that you need before the first render and don't need to repeat it again, then the mounting phase (empty array `[]`) is when you need to fetch this data.

Comment: Thank you could you please update your answer and fill [] with an state ? thanks again

Comment: thank you very much , it's work .. are you similar with EXPO ?

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with expo

Comment: Very good could you please see this topic : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65103398/expo-react-native-task-manager-never-run

Answer (score 1):

Every time the text changes, it triggers function that is changing the state, and every time the state changes, the component re-runs, so does the console.log.
You should wrap your console.log or function in **useEffect** hook, like this:

```
useEffect(()=> {
console.log('...')
}, [])
```

Comment: So , how could I prevent  that ?

Comment: So , how could I prevent  that ?

Comment: I had a function there that load data for textinput just for init , but it run every time on change and prevent saving any more..

Answer (score 1):

good day, as it seems to me, see react compares the old virtualDOM and the new modified virtualDOM, that is, when you did setState, you caused a change in the state of the component, and since console. log finds it in the body, it just drew it.

Answer (score 1):

when you are changing text inside input you are setting your state.

```
onChangeText={(username) => set_out1(username)}
```

Now when your state changes it calls render method. so your component will compare its dom with old dom and re-render the component .

to prevent this use can use lifecycle methods or conditional statements to avoid the method call. or you can use formik.